# C# Backing up data to file which can be restored later

Tags: c#, sql-server, serialization, backup

I'm looking for some feedback as to what is the best way to back data up from a sql server database which can be restored at a later date. This back up needs to be in a file which the user can use to restore data at a later date.

Does anyone have any ideas or examplea as to the best way to do this using C# and Sql Server?

EDIT:
This shouldn't back the whole database, just a set of data specified by the user using dates.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, you want to audit just some of your data for changes (as opposed to having a full DB backup) and to be able to selectively roll them back to a previous state.

If that's what you want to do, you may do that from within sql by using a "audit" table and populating it via triggers on the table where your original data is stored (i.e. each time a row is inserted/updated/deleted the trigger will write on the "audit" table what the previous value was and when it was changed).

See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20071006100909/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-audit-changes-to-sql-server-data.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of Code. i have used this before.

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread202843.html